# Closed curve for an analityc function

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-functions, maximum-principle, analytic-continuation

If I have an analityc function $f(z)$ on a domain $B \subset \mathbb{C}$ and a simple and closed curve $C$ that encloses $B$, and if $|f|$ is constant over C, the $f$ is constant on $B$?

I haven’t found a counterexample but i dont know how to apply the maximum principle or apply some analityc continuation. Please some help with this.

Comment: $f(z) = z$ on $|z| = 1$ ? Otherwise $f(z) =c \frac{z+b}{\overline{b}z+1}$ [with $|b| < 1$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_transformation#Subgroups_of_the_M%C3%B6bius_group) on $|z|=1$

Comment: @reuns: Can you post this as an answer so that this question can be moved out of the Unanswered queue?